# Why can't table be listed in oracle db?

Tags: oracle

in oracle database on linux server;

```
desc table_x;    =>  getting data
select * from table_x;   => getting data
SELECT table_name from all_tables;   => it is not in the list
```

How can I get this table to appear in the list?

Thanks.

Comment: Littlefoot's suggestions are the likely culprits, but I also wonder if you might just be looking in the list for 'table_x' in lowercase to match how you query it, and it is in the list as 'TABLE_X' - which is normal for a non-quoted identifier.

Comment: Check `ALL_OBJECTS`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it isn't a table that is contained in `all_tables`. What is it, then?

Might be a **synonym**, so try

```
select * from all_synonyms where synonym_name = 'TABLE_X';
```

Or, a **view**:

```
select * From all_views where view_name = 'TABLE_X';
```

Comment: thanhs for reply but not solved my problem.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the listing of the table is somehow blocked. If this is the problem, how do I overcome it?

Comment: Shouldn't be *blocked*. Try to query ALL_OBJECTS and see what it really is.

Comment: SQL> select * from all_objects where object_name like '%table_x%';

no rows selected

SQL>



SQL> desc table_x;
 Name     Null?    Type
 ------------------------
 col1     NUMBER
 col2     NUMBER
 col3  NOT NULL NUMBER
 col4 NUMBER
 col5     NOT NULL NUMBER

Comment: Try `where upper(object_name) like '%TABLE_X%'` because object names are *usually* stored in uppercase.